# Draw to WebGL canvas directly from C++ application

Tags: qt, canvas, opengl-es, webgl

I have been experimenting with Qt Webkit to render a video element in the browser.  All of my frames are decoded by a C++ application (source video packets received over the network), and I can display the video in an element using Qt as described here: [QtWebEngine rendering native Qt widgets in DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661280/qtwebengine-rendering-native-qt-widgets-in-dom) but I am limited by the z-index issues of Qt Webkit :(

Instead, I was wondering if any of the following are possible and if anyone has achieved anything this before.

I have a C++ application that launches a Chrome Embedded Framework window (basically a browser window). Is there any way my C++ application can render video directly into that browser window - using webGL or a similar library?  Maybe there is some way I can use openGL in the C++ app to write to the graphics card memory and have webGL read off the graphics card data - this would be awesome if such a technique existed but I fear sandboxing will not allow this.

e.g.

```
Browser webGL surface/object <--- C++ application <--- file/network data
```

A (very!) naive approach would be for the browser window to connect to the C++ core application using a websocket on loopback address, and the websocket stream the surfaces to the browser.  These surfaces could then be drawn to a html5 canvas or used by webGL - this would probably be terrible in terms of latency though.

e.g

```
Browser <--- websocket <--- C++ decode <--- file/network data
```

Many thanks - any other suggestions for alternative libraries I could use for this / code examples would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Qt 5.10 introduced the [Qt Quick WebGL Streaming Plugin](https://www.ics.com/blog/whats-new-qt-510). It allows you to stream a QML application to a browser. Not sure if this would help in your case, but I wanted to make you aware of it, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest CEF:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework
It has full support for anything a modern Google Chrome browser can do. In fact it is the Chrome Browser.

Answer (score 0):

> ...render a video element in the browser. All of my frames are decoded by
> a C++ application (source video packets received over the network),
> and I can display the video in an element...

Maybe, we do not clearly understand the task, but you are trying to read a `stream` from `HTML` (you have two main blocks: C++ as video converter, HTML/WebGL as video output - here I drop away your block with transferring video to HTML).

First, start with HTML. To display video in browser you need:

```html
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src="http://localhost/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Second, you need a source for your stream. It can be a C++ program as yours, but original Question says: "source video packets received over the network". It means, that you already have a stream in some format. You just need to convert it to `ogg`. The best solution is `ffmpeg`.

If your program on C++ already can produce a stream in some format (for example in ogg), then the problem is not so big for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is good option for you.

***writen c++/c code port to -> to html/js***

https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/index.html

I take data for compile args from python emsdk scripts.
Here some interest example like SDL, GL, keyboard, mouse event.

```
C GL Shader:

  emcc sdl2-c-shader/sdl2glshader.c -s USE_SDL=2
           -s LEGACY_GL_EMULATION=1 -s GL_UNSAFE_OPTS=0
           -o sdl2-c-shader/build/sdl2.html

Mouse events:

  emcc mouse-events/test_html5_mouse.c -O2 -g1 --closure 1
  -s DISABLE_DEPRECATED_FIND_EVENT_TARGET_BEHAVIOR=1
  -DAUTOMATE_SUCCESS=1  -o mouse-events/build/tmouse.html

Draw object, declare in typescript, opengles2

  emcc sdl-ts-declare/webgl_draw_triangle.c -lGL
  -s OFFSCREEN_FRAMEBUFFER=1 -DEXPLICIT_SWAP=1
  -DDRAW_FROM_CLIENT_MEMORY=1 -s FULL_ES2=1
  -o sdl-ts-declare/build/gles2test.html

Keyboard (c)

  emcc keyboard-c/test_keyboard_codes.c -O2 -g1 --closure 1
  -s DISABLE_DEPRECATED_FIND_EVENT_TARGET_BEHAVIOR=1
  -DAUTOMATE_SUCCESS=1  -o keyboard-c/build/keyboard-mouse.html

Write file (cpp)

  emcc write-file/write_file.cpp -s ENVIRONMENT=web
  --closure 1 -o write-file/build/test.html

Draw trianlge object, (c, opengles2)

  emcc webgl-triangle/webgl_draw_triangle.c -lGL
  -s OFFSCREEN_FRAMEBUFFER=1 -DEXPLICIT_SWAP=1
  -DDRAW_FROM_CLIENT_MEMORY=1 -s FULL_ES2=1
  -o webgl-triangle/build/test.html

geometry cube SDL

 // self.btest('cubegeom_pre3.c',
 // reference='cubegeom_pre2.png',
 // args=['-s', 'LEGACY_GL_EMULATION=1', '-lGL', '-lSDL'])

 emcc cubegeom_pre3.c -s LEGACY_GL_EMULATION=1 -lGL
 -lSDL -o build/test.html preload-file res

Test mem-cpu

  emcc cpu-mem/benchmark_memcpy.cpp -DBUILD_FOR_SHELL
  -I tests/tick.h -s WASM=0 -s TOTAL_MEMORY=512MB
  --memory-init-file 1  -o cpu-mem/nik.html
```

Take a look :

https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/c-cpp-to-javascript